# component tag in facelets library

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I am using Facelets with JSF 2.0. In the facelets tag library there is a tag called `<ui:component>`.
It inserts an instance of UIComponent to the tree and it trims the tags outside itself.

Can anyone explain me what is the use of this kind of functionality? Why would any one want to add `UIComponent` instance to the tree?

I searched a lot for the examples of component tag but didn't find any.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info

Answer (score 0):

The [`<ui:component>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/component.html) inserts a physical `UIComponent` instance in the component tree, with all the content as its children.

The [`<ui:composition>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/composition.html) does not insert any physical `UIComponent` instance in the component tree, instead, it inserts all the content as children of its parent. You cannot find it via `findComponent()`.

[Composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) use implicitly `<ui:component>` because it basically introduces a `NamingContainer` component which allows reusing the same composite component multiple times in a parent without the risk to end up with duplicate component ID errors caused by the composite's children.